# How to correctly use #ifdef DEBUG / RELEASE values in Swift Code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, conditional-compilation

This question is **NOT** about how to create/use Objective-C like `#ifdef` statements in Swift, which has been discussed in other questions.

This question is about how to use existing Objective-C code from existing `#ifdef` statements in Swift:

I am working on migrating my existing iOS 9+ app from `Objective-C` to `Swift`. While large parts of the app still use `Objective-C` new View Controllers, Classe, etc. are added using Swift.

The `Objective-C` code uses `#ifdef` statements to create different code for debugging and release and for different app targets like a Freemium and a Pro version:

```
#ifdef PRO_VER
    #define APP_NAME @"My App Pro"
#else
    #define APP_NAME @"My App"
#endif
```

## The Problem

When using these constants in `Objective-C` everything is fine. When using the same constants within the same target in Swift, they always have the non-pro value:

```
// Using in Objective-C within the Pro Target
NSLog(@"The objc app name is: %@", APP_NAME);

// Using in Swift within the Pro Target
print("The Swift app name is: \(APP_NAME)")


Output:
    The objc app name is: My App Pro
    The Swift app name is: My App
```

So, the same constant has different values when being used in Swift or Objective-C.

Of course, this could be solved by creating a static Objective-C method/property which returns the correct value which is then be used by the Swift code. However, this would be quite hacky and cumbersome.

**Is there a better solution to get the correct values from within Swift code?**

Comment: check this https://medium.com/@danielgalasko/change-your-api-endpoint-environment-using-xcode-configurations-in-swift-c1ad2722200e#.ekhevi2v8

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I can see this is *just* an explanation of how to use conditional compiling in Swift. This is not what was asked. I know that there are different solutions to compile / create / use different Swift code for different targets. The question is, how to use existing conditional Objective-C code in Swift, since Swift seems to only see/use the default code.

Answer (score 2):

> The Objective-C code uses `#ifdef` statements to create different code for debugging and release and for different app targets like a Freemium and a Pro version

You can't say `#define` in Swift. Instead:

- Swift can use `#if DEBUG` to create different code for debugging and release.
- To distinguish between custom defined constants, add them to the target's Active Compilation Conditions build setting.

Those are in fact the same thing, because the reason `#if DEBUG` works is that it *is* in the target's Active Compilation Conditions.

(And there are various other things that `#if` can distinguish between, such as Swift version, and whether we're compiling for the simulator or a device.)

Comment: And you might find this article useful: http://onebigfunction.com/ios/2017/03/14/flavor-ios/

Comment: Thanks, but this is also not what I am looking for: As said before I know that Swift uses other methods to create conditional code and thus the question is **NOT** how to create conditional code in Swift but how to use **existing conditional code** from Objective-C in Swift. As described in the question accessing **the same constant** both from Objective-C and from Swift returns different values which is quite bad for a **constant**...

Comment: You can’t. Swift cannot somehow “see” an Objective C define. If you think about it, you’ll see the idea makes no sense. The define is an instruction to the objective C compiler / preprocessor.

Comment: This is not about the `#define`s (which can be used / accessed without any problem from Swift code) but about the conditional created in Objective-C using `#ifdef`. I use `#ifdev` to create different code A or B depending on the target. I would understand if Swift could not access the such code, but it can. However, it does not use the correct code but always the `#else` code...